# sass mixin with $var for Base64

Tags: css, svg, sass, mixins

I am trying to create simple mixin for my svg icons.

**Mixin:**

```
@mixin ico($position, $size, $image) {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,$image);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size : $size;
    background-position: $position;
    background-color: $blue-dark;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

**SASS error:**

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"...image: url(data\": expected comma, was \":image/svg+xml;...\"\A
```

Not sure how to go around it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation here.  You may need to quote it and then use the `unquote()` function.

```
$blue-dark: blue;
@mixin ico($position, $size, $image) {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{$image});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size : $size;
    background-position: $position;
    background-color: $blue-dark;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.foo {
    @include ico(0, 10, foo);
}
```

It's worth noting that if you want to be able to provide a fallback for browsers that don't support SVG backgrounds, you'll want to use a background shorthand that includes `background-size`:

```
.foo {
    background: url(foo.png) no-repeat;
    background: url(foo.svg) 0 0 / auto auto no-repeat;
}
```